# multiply chars from array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unicode, char, multiplication

I have a problem multiply char values with an integer. 
Instead of the right values, I get very big values.
final is here = 32487000 but why. When I check the value of the array, I see its added with '51', '50' etc...

I have tried many ways to convert that, ut its every time the same problem...

I would be very thankful for any ideas.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int final = 5;
    char[] arr = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4'}

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
      final = final * arr[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which problem you are trying to solve. This question sounds too much like an XY problem (you are trying to solve problem X and came up with the solution as shown here, but this has problem Y and you're now asking for a solution to Y rather than to X).

Comment: Anyway, the issue with `char`s is that they can hold many non-digit values. How do you want `'A'` to be treated? As a hex char with the decimal value 10?

Answer (score 4):

When you multiply a `char` with an `int`, the `char` will first be converted to its character code. The character code for `'1'` is `49`, and `5*49` will be 245. This issue occurs throughout your entire loop. Instead, you want to parse your `char` into an `int` before you multiply it with `final`:

```
int num = int.Parse(arr[i].ToString());
```

Once you have your char in numeric form, you can multiply it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    int final = 5;
    char[] arr = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4'};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
      int num = int.Parse(arr[i].ToString()); // convert to int
      final = final * num;
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(final); // 120
}
```

Comment: Or, simply use `int[]` for the array.

Comment: @MrLister yep, that would be the simplest way if OP can use an int array

Comment: Yes. The problem is not so much that the code value of char '1' is not 1, but that they are using chars in the first place. See also my comments to the question.